# What is robots.txt disallowing with Disallow: / for Googlebot image?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

Robots.txt – It is currently disallowing “/” – GoogleBot image.

Just curious what that is disallowing and if it’s important for search engines to index? You don’t want to restrict any search robots from indexing important pages.  Could somebody explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's blocking Google from indexing their images. This is because they do not want their images coming up in Google's image search. They may have copyrighted images and don't want there images to be potentially used without their permission.

Answer (score 0):

That means that Google will not index any images on that site.